# Linux process stack overrun by local variables (stack guarding)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, stack-memory

From [What is the purpose of the _chkstk() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400118/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-chkstk-function):

> At the end of the stack, there is one guard page mapped as
>   inaccessible memory -- if the program accesses it (because it is
>   trying to use more stack than is currently mapped), there's an access
>   violation.

[`_chkstk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/-win32-chkstk) is a special compiler-helper function which

> ensures that there is enough space for the local variables

i.e. it's doing some stack probing (here is an [LLVM example](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/i386/chkstk2.S)).
This case is Windows-specific. So Windows has some solution to the problem.

Let's consider the similar conditions under Linux (or some other Unix-like): we have a lot of function's local variables. The first stack variable access is behind the stack segment (e.g. `mov eax, [esp-LARGE_NUMBER]`, here esp-LARGE_NUMBER is something behind the stack segment). Is there any features to prevent possible page fault or whatever in Linux (perhaps other Unix-like) or development tools like [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), [clang](/questions/tagged/clang), etc? Does `-fstack-check` ([GCC stack checking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-Checking.html)) somehow solve this problem? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908736/how-windows-thread-stack-guard-page-mechanism-works-in-case-of-uninitialized-loc/25911864#25911864) states that it is something very similar to `_chkstk()`.

P.S. These posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217778/linux-kernel-behaviour-on-heap-overrun-or-stack-overflow), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908736/how-windows-thread-stack-guard-page-mechanism-works-in-case-of-uninitialized-loc) didn't help a lot.

P.P.S. In general, the question is about implementation differences between OSs (foremost **Linux** vs Windows) approaches of **struggling** with huge amount of **stack variables, that climb behind the stack segment**. Both C++ and C tags are added because it's about Linux native binary producing, but the assembly code is compiler-related.

Comment: The fact that StackClash exists suggests: nothing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli updated.

Comment: gcc got options to include stack guard which at least allows program to create correct dump if call stack was nuked.

Comment: On linux you can set the stack size with `ulimit` or `pthread_attr_setstacksize`. This memory (as usual) won't be allocated by the OS immediately. It gets allocated when it's actually used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_chkstk` does stack *probes* to make sure each page is touched in order after a (potentially) large allocation, e.g. an alloca.  Because Windows will only grow the stack one page at a time up to the stack size limit.

Touching that "guard page" triggers stack growth.  It doesn't guard against stack overflow; I think you're misinterpreting the meaning of "guard page" in this usage.

The function name is also potentially misleading.  [`_chkstk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/-win32-chkstk) docs simply say: *Called by the compiler when you have more than one page of local variables in your function.*  It doesn't truly *check* anything, it just makes sure that intervening pages have been touched before memory around `esp`/`rsp` gets used.  i.e. the only possible effects are: nothing (possibly including a valid soft page fault) or an invalid page-fault on stack overflow (trying to touch a page that Windows refused to grow the stack to include.)  It *ensures* that the stack pages are allocated by unconditionally writing them.

I guess you could look at this as checking for a stack clash by making sure you touch an unmappable page before continuing in the case of stack overflow.

---

**Linux will grow the main-thread stack<sup>1</sup> by any number of pages (up to the stack size limit set by `ulimit -s`; default 8MiB)** when you touch memory below old stack pages *if it's above the current stack pointer*.

**If you touch memory outside the growth limit, or don't move the stack pointer first, it will just segfault.**  Thus Linux doesn't need stack probes, merely to move the stack pointer by as many bytes as you want to reserve.  Compilers know this and emit code accordingly.

See also [How is Stack memory allocated when using 'push' or 'sub' x86 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790666/how-is-stack-memory-allocated-when-using-push-or-sub-x86-instructions) for more low-level details on what the Linux kernel does, and what glibc pthreads on Linux does.

**A sufficiently large `alloca` on Linux can move the stack all the way past the bottom of the stack growth region, beyond the guard pages below that, and into another mapping; this is a Stack Clash.**  https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2017/06/19/the-stack-clash  It of course requires that the program uses a potentially-huge size for alloca, dependent on user input.  The [mitigation for CVE-2017-1000364](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-1000364) is to leave a 1MiB guard region, requiring a much larger alloca than normal to get past the guard pages.

This 1MiB guard region is below the `ulimit -s` (8MiB) growth limit, not below the current stack pointer.  It's separate from Linux's normal stack growth mechanism.

---

#### `gcc -fstack-check`

**The effect of `gcc -fstack-check` is essentially the same as what's always needed on Windows** (which MSVC does by calling `_chkstk`): touch stack pages in between previous and new stack pointer when moving it by a large or runtime-variable amount.

But the purpose / benefit of these probes is different on Linux; it's never needed for correctness in a bug-free program on GNU/Linux.  It "only" defends against stack-clash bugs/exploits.

On x86-64 GNU/Linux, `gcc -fstack-check` will (for functions with a VLA or large fixe-size array) add a loop that does stack probes with `or qword ptr [rsp], 0` along with `sub rsp,4096`.  For known fixed array sizes, it can be just a single probe.  The code-gen doesn't look very efficient; it's normally never used on this target.  (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFYADKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYlysAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF09o4uRu6enFZKKmp0DATMxATBxqaWisqYqoHpmQTRzm4eXooZWTmh%2BQp15Q6VcdWJAJSKqAbEyBwA5ABuqHjoANQ0qBAOBJMAVF3iAMyyFgCC4ltjE5OumXP0k/4AXphdk%2BIA7Bubk4%2BT85OZxOJm0ueYHwAia/cntNULM3it1jttjd/ltIXspodiAB9Kh4AAemHQ3wgV1ugKeLzeH2kiQsFj%2BAMmAHoqZNuBYAJwANkm6FQmAUkyMBlYam87Em3mIqHcCkhQOptMSkm4jwg9OZBwAngQOVc2RzJpJXug%2BMxBichSKOeKnjMIGCAZDbr8hj1WCAhmYhqRTEMLC7UI6dHI5Kc%2BgNMNdJKtOC6CI6PV0egBrECSG4AOhD3AZkgZ3BuZlWZhuvAdQ24LrdHtIXqGLoUICsEfddtIcFgSDQRm8eHYZAoEBbbY7IGAadIqN5HirEFckZdrgcmSVjrDpBbRi0BAA8rRWHO66QsEYRMB2JOd3hiEU1CMOUfMBjkAZVfOXfNlEfWHhXMRZ3osA/SARiHgjAfHoaHoJg2A4Hh%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)** compiler explorer example that passes a stack array to a non-inline function.)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-Checking.html describes some GCC internal parameters that control what `-fstack-check` does.

If you want absolute safety against stack-clash attacks, this should do it.  It's not needed for normal operation, though, and a 1MiB guard page is enough for most people.

---

**Note that `-fstack-protector-strong` is completely different, and guards against overwrite of the return address by buffer overruns on local arrays.**  Nothing to do with stack clashes, and the attack is against stuff already on the stack above a small local array, not against other regions of memory by *moving* the stack a lot.

---

Footnote 1:  Thread stacks on Linux (for threads other than the initial one) have to be fully allocated up front because the magic growth feature doesn't work.  Only the initial aka main thread of a process can have that.

(There's an `mmap(MAP_GROWSDOWN)` feature but it's *not* safe because there's no limit, and because nothing stops other dynamic allocations from randomly picking a page close below the current stack, limiting future growth to a tiny size before a stack clash.  Also because it only grows if you touch the guard page, so it would need stack probes.  For these showstopper reasons, **`MAP_GROWSDOWN` is not used for thread stacks**. The internal mechanism for the main stack relies on different magic in the kernel which *does* prevent other allocations from stealing space.)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for clarifying. So `-fstack-check` has nothing to do with the mentioned problem?

Comment: *"It doesn't guard against stack overflow; I think you're misinterpreting"* - Yep. It has nothing to do with stack overflow. But page guard by itself looks like subquality work. It makes real sense just with compiler fixtures like `_chkstk`, doesn't it?

Comment: The first question in comment about `-fstack-check` is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908736/how-windows-thread-stack-guard-page-mechanism-works-in-case-of-uninitialized-loc/25911864#25911864)

Comment: @narotello: `-fstack-check` guards against stack-clash attacks, in case the 1MiB guard region below the main stack isn't enough.  (e.g. to armor a codebase that carelessly uses potentially huge unchecked VLAs according to user input).  It wasn't clear from the question if you were talking about stack clashes or just normal stack *growth* mechanism, because on Windows that's what `_chkstk` is, as well as having the side-effect of making stack clashes impossible.  And BTW; the comment under Hans's answer you linked is correct; `_chkstk` is not a debug feature; the answer is wrong.

Comment: @narotello: I updated this answer with some info about stack clashes and what `gcc -fstack-check` actually does when targeting Linux.  I'd forgotten about stack clashes when initially writing this.  (Good code doesn't use potentially huge sizes for VLAs or alloca in the first place.)

Comment: As a result, one can came to the conclusion that the regular code written for Windows needs to be emitted with `_chkstk()` (or something like this) just because of little guard gap's size (e.g. 4K)? I.e. `fstack-check` does the same thing as `_chkstk()`?

Comment: *"It's not needed for normal operation"* - and if the Windows will increase gap's size (e.g. up to 1 MiB) - `_chkstk()` will be unessential for compilers in case of *"normal operation" "for most people"*? (as well as `fstack-check` is optional with 1MiB gap)

Comment: @NK-cell: That doesn't all follow.  On GNU/Linux with default `ulimit -s` it's safe to allocate a 4MiB array on the stack, and then touch the bottom element first with no intervening stack probes.  Windows with a 1MiB growth increment would still need to touch every 1MiB.  Linux's 1MiB "guard region" isn't a "growth area", it's below the 8MiB growth limit and just reserved to make stack clash attacks harder.  Updated to hopefully help future readers avoid that misunderstanding, thanks.